# I am using PHP to determine the subdomain, but changing page doesn't change the result

Tags: domain-access

In Drupal 7 I am using the Domain module to allow multiple subdomains of the format sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, etc.

When I am sure that I can correctly identify the current subdomain, I will use a php test in the Block Visibility Settings to decide which menu to show to which subdomain.

To check I can use PHP to identify the current subdomain, I have set up a block with the code.

```php
global $base_url;
$current_path = $base_url . '/' . current_path();
echo $base_url;
echo  "<br>";
echo $current_path;
echo  "<br>";

$actual_link = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo $actual_link;
```

The result shows the subdomain from the first page that I access. When I switch page to another subdomain the new subdomain is not shown; the original one is still shown.

How can I can see the correct subdomain for the current page?

Comment: Sounds like Drupal is caching the result. To fix this, you'd have to add a cache context for subdomain to the cached item (likely the page cache). Explaining how to do so is more than I can explain here though, it would take some debugging and testing, and likely a few hours development.

Comment: In fact I have changed the code I show in the original post, and I now end the code with a clearstatcache() statement. It has made no difference.

Comment: It's probably not that cache. Maybe the page cache.

Comment: Neither `db_query("DELETE FROM {cache_page};");
db_query("DELETE FROM {cache_path};");` work either

Comment: Might be cached in more than one place. But it's not something we can debug on a Q&A forum.